# Previously defined function is now undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, localhost, undefined

I have the provided code which defines the function slider and at some later point, once the document is ready I try to use the function.

This works perfectly when I run on **localhost**, but when everything is uploaded to my server, I get an undefined error.

I can put break points in my code when the function is defined and subsequently later when it is used (but no longer defined when run from the server).

Since it works fine on localhost, and I see the function is defined before being used when running from the server, I'm not sure where to start to look for my problem.

The only thing I can think of is that in between the time the function is defined, there is some other version of jQuery being loaded which does not have this definition, but wouldn't this also happen when running on localhost, or could the time it takes for the server to send the files make a difference?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slider').slider({...});
});
/* this gets called first */
(function ($, j, k, l) {
    $.fn.slider = function (g) {...}
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

**NEW...**

I have implemented 2 solutions which both seem to work but, I still wonder about possible causes and why I must resort to these solutions?

**Solution 1**: I simply remove the parameter jQuery from my script. This works since I include jQuery before my script, but I worry that the original problem could re-appear,

```
/* Now simply using the globally defined jquery object*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slider').slider({...});
});
/* this gets called first */
(function (j, k, l) {
    $.fn.slider = function (g) {...}
})(window, document); /* removed JQuery parameter here*/
```

**Solution 2**: I capture the passed in jQuery object as a new non-standard name and writing my script I continue to refer the $ for any jQuery operation that does not involve my slider function, then when I want to use the slider function I use my saved jQuery context - this solution seems more robust- any thoughts? I still would like input as to what the original problem could be?

```
/* Here I use both the globally defined jquery object and my saved context */
(function (myJQ, j, k, l) {
    myJQ.fn.slider = function (g) {...}
/* I move the onReady function inside so I can reference myJQ */ 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        myJQ('.slider').slider({...});/*use myJQ to call my slider function */
/* otherwise I use $*/
    });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: And the error points to `$('.slider').slider({...});`? Or is another function not defined?

Comment: It says that slider is undefined even though i can step through the code as it defines the slider function.